# Google Hangout API for IOS

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts

I've been searching for a reference for the Google Hangout API used on IOS.  I was told that with in the past week or so Google released the hangout API to run on IOS but I haven't been able to find anything... anyone else hear anything about this?  Or perhaps it's been around for some time and I'm just not seeing it?

Comment: Is there any change on this?

Comment: https://twitter.com/abbood/status/732191386548637697

Answer (score 0):

Hangout Apps (and the Hangout API) is only supported on desktop browsers. You can launch and join a Hangout without apps from the iOS Google+ application.

Comment: a reference would be a truly beautiful thing here